# How to display all posts with today's same month and day only?

Tags: query, date

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. I have many posts. I want it so that when someone pulls up the site, the front page shows all the posts that were done on the same month and day -- but disregards the year. So, if I were to pull up the website on Jan. 30, I would see all posts done on Jan. 30th of ANY year... a historical listing. I was also thinking of doing it by category, if the category was named Jan-30, is there a way I can get the system to take today's date and compare it to the categories, and show the one that matches (no year, of course)?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Okay, you guys are BRILLIANT. I actually tried all three methods (after Milo corrected my placement, LOL) and each one worked PERFECTLY. Thank you, Darren, Chris and Milo -- you saved my sanity!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the [`date_query` parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) added in version 3.7.

To modify the main query on your posts page before it is run and apply the `date_query` parameters, we use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action:

```
function historical_posts_list( $query ){
    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $date_query = array(
            array(
                'month' => date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
                'day' => date( 'j', current_time( 'timestamp' ) )
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'date_query', $date_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'historical_posts_list' );
```

If the page you want this on isn't your posts page, you can add a custom query in your template with the same parameters, and run a separate loop:

```
$posts_from_today = new WP_Query( array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'month' => date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
            'day' => date( 'j', current_time( 'timestamp' ) )
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );

if( $posts_from_today->have_posts() ){
    while( $posts_from_today->have_posts() ){
        $posts_from_today->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Milo, I'm trying this out and I put it on the index.php since that's where my loop  is (stop me if I'm putting it in the wrong place!). I wrapped it in php tags and put it before the loop starts. Now, I'm not getting any error but on the other hand, it's showing me all the recent posts and not today's, so I've clearly put it in the wrong location... help?

Comment: the first example would go in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: See, that's why I needed you guys. <lol>

Answer (score 2):

```
$q  = new \WP_Query([
  'monthnum' => date('n'), // beware the date function!
  'day'      => date('j'),
]);

while ($q->have_posts()) {
  $q->the_post();
  // ...
}
wp_reset_query();
```

See the documentation on [date parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).

Since you want to modify the home page query specifically, you might hook into `pre_get_posts` and modify the main query on the home page only.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse174669_pre_get_posts');
function wpse174669_pre_get_posts($q)
{
    if (is_home() && $q->is_main_query()) {
        $q->set('ignore_sticky_posts', true);
        $q->set('monthnum', date('n'));
        $q->set('day', date('j'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go the Category route, you could do something like this:

First, get a slug of today's date:

```
$date_slug = current_time('M-d');
```

Then, create a taxonomy query argument array:

```
$tax_query =  array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $date_slug,
    )
);
```

Then, build a query using the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class:

```
$r = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    )
);
```

Then, build your [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop):

```
<?php if ($r->have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```